# What classes from Jeffrey Richter's PowerThreading library are people using?

Tags: .net, multithreading, concurrency

Jeffrey Richter is looking for some input on how people are using his PowerThreading library. If anyone out there is using this, what parts of it are you using? He is looking to clean up the library and wants to know what classes people are using.

http://www.wintellect.com/PowerThreading.aspx

EDIT: See http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/PowerThreading/message/88

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An indirect answer (I don't use that library myself) - if I was looking at complex threading, I'd be very tempted to look at what the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163340.aspx) has to offer in the current CTP, especially looking forward to .NET 4.0.

Comment: asked this of Richter and he gave a good/detailed answer to this question. I'll ask if I could post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I watched video linked from MSDN news feed, then downloaded his library shortly after.

I haven't really had a chance to get into it too much but I can tell you this, his samples need a *lot* of work.  I took me 15 minutes of poking around to figure out what I should build/run before I could actually even view a sample.  When I did get a sample running it was too obscure for me to decide how I could implement it in my own projects.

If I hadn't watched the [video](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2008/12/03/jeff-richter-video-on-asynchronous-programming-and-his-power-threading-library.aspx) first I would have no idea what his library does or how powerful it can be.